# Getting permission denied error with docker remove

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I'm following a tutorial and in the current step, i'm supposed to remove any preexisting docker containers with this

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
```

I usually have to use sudo to use docker commands, so I tried

```
sudo docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
```

But I get this

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.32/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.

Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers
```

Usually I get permission errors when I forget to use sudo, but in this case I have it.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried this

```
sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -aq)
```

but get

```
"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.

Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have any preexisting containers, Result of this command `sudo docker ps -aq` seems to be empty, which will result in total command as `sudo docker rm -f` without any container ID's. You can skip this command as there were no preexisting containers.

Answer (score 0):

You are combining a couple different issues between the need for `sudo` and a potentially "empty" container list noted in another answer.

The other answer is exactly correct that this combination of commands might result in the `docker rm` error as the `docker ps -aq` could return nothing, leaving the `docker rm` command with no options, prompting the help text.

Of course, there are two reasons the "inner" command could return nothing:

1. there are actually zero running or exited containers; in this case you can ignore the error to `docker rm`, or run the `docker ps -aq` command by itself to convince yourself there are no containers returned.
2. The other reason is if the command failed due to lack of permission to talk to the Docker daemon. In your first example you show you are using `sudo` on the remove command, but not on the inner `ps` command, revealing the error that it could not talk to the docker socket. The output could be confusing because you are being shown two errors; one from each command: "*Got permission denied...*" is from the non-sudo version of `docker ps` and the second line "*docker rm requires at least ..*" is from `docker rm` not having anything to remove because the first command failed.

The reason you need `sudo` to use the `docker` client is because it talks to the Docker engine over a UNIX socket located at `/var/lib/docker.sock` which is controlled for write access by `root` (the uid owner) and the `docker` group owner. More info on using `sudo` for Docker commands is in the [post-installation setup docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user) as well as information on how to allow a normal user to have access to the socket, **if you so choose**. Make sure you read the warnings on that page about what that allows before making the decision between requiring sudo or adding your user to the `docker` group.

If you do add your user the `docker` group, you will no longer have to use `sudo` for Docker commands and can ignore any guides/tutorials which have `sudo` prefixed in front of all docker client commands.